# Using an API from a remote repository

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build, dependencies

***UPDATE***: I was compiling my source files using `javac`, which was (obviously) not linking my dependency on the YahooFinance API, as specified in my `build.gradle` file. I issued a `gradle build` command instead, and the dependency was successfully linked.

I'm writing a Java program that uses an API from the Maven Central repository, located [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/yahoofinance-api/YahooFinanceAPI/3.2.0/).

I believe I have properly connected to the API from my `build.gradle` file, because when I run `gradle dependencies` from the command line, I get a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` message in return.

However when I try to use the API in my code, something like...

```
import yahoofinance.YahooFinance;
// ...
YahooFinance yf = new YahooFinance();
```

... my program will not compile. The compilation errors:

```
Allocate.java:7: error: package yahoofinance does not exist
import yahoofinance.YahooFinance;
                   ^
Allocate.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        YahooFinance yf = new YahooFinance();
        ^
  symbol:   class YahooFinance
  location: class Allocate
Allocate.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        YahooFinance yf = new YahooFinance();
                              ^
  symbol:   class YahooFinance
  location: class Allocate
3 errors
```

What must I fix to be able to use this API in my code?

Here is my build.gradle file, if that is any help:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.yahoofinance-api', name: 'YahooFinanceAPI', version: '3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: The build.gradle seems OK. What is the compilation error you get?

Comment: @yonisha See changes for compilation errors

Comment: 'javac' executable is unaware of gradle and the libraries downloaded by it (unless you specify their location using the '-cp' switch). Anyway, running the 'gradle build' command will generate a folder 'build\libs\ which will include your compiled sources. Isn't it what you need?